# downloading from a URI : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: c#

I get the following exception when I attempt to download an item from a specific location

```
        public void Mydownload(string uri, string destinationPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (FileStream file = File.Create(destinationPath))
                {
                    long sz = response.ContentLength;
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    int chunkBytes;
                    int progress = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    while ((chunkBytes = stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        file.Write(buffer, 0, chunkBytes);
                        bytesRead += chunkBytes;
                        int currentProgress = (int)(((double)sz) / bytesRead);                   
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception c)
            {
                Console.Write(c.ToString()); //Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: size
            }
        }
```

I noticed that the program crashes during the second iteration of the while loop on the statement

```
while ((chunkBytes = stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length)) > 0)
```

I am not sure what I might be doing wrong any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you mean to use a single equals? Shouldn't it be chunkBytes == stream.Read ?

Comment: don't think so `(chunkBytes = stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length))` is being compared to `0`

Comment: Ya I just realized that as well.

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace?

Comment: But I think that the culprit is the `bytesRead += chunkBytes;` line - you probably read more than `buffer.Length` and that makes `bytesRead` bigger than `buffer.Length` in the `stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length)` call - see `offset` parameter in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: The exception stack trace doesnt have much info appart from the fact that the exception occurs during the second iteration of the loop

Comment: @Rajeshwar It will at least show the line that throws. And that line is probably `(chunkBytes = stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `stream.Read` is the offset of the output buffer to begin writing to. You are doing:

```
stream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, buffer.Length)
```

yet `bytesRead` is incremented as the data is written:

```
file.Write(buffer, 0, chunkBytes);
bytesRead += chunkBytes;
```

On the first iteration `bytesRead` is 0 so the start index is in range for the target buffer, but on the second it will probably have been incremented by the length of the buffer after the first read. At this point it will be an out of range index, hence the exception.

You always want to read from the start of the buffer i.e.

```
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```